# How to detect programmatically when other apps are closed / force stopped

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i need to perform an action when other apps are closed / force stopped. This detection has to be made from a service which is been running in the background once started. Making the service to run continuously is not a problem but making detection when other apps are closed is the problem. Please do anyone have any solution.....

Comment: Detecting things happening on the system is done using `BroadcastReceiver`.  I'm not sure though that "force close" are broadcast.

Comment: The /proc file system provides information about the running processes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to detect when an app is force stopped. Even the app being stopped doesn't get that information. You can detect if an app is currently closed by using the BroadcastReceiver. Here's a pretty decent tutorial on using that: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-11.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any official way in which Android allows apps to listen in on when other apps are forced to close. So you’d have to poke around under the hood.

Disclaimer: Doing so is unsupported. While just reading information is unlikely to cause any harm, there’s no guarantee that it will work universally. If you get it to work on your particular build of Android, may still fail on different builds. Also, Google keeps locking down features in Android with every new version, so there’s a high likelihood a future update may break things.

I haven’t actually tried any of the below, hence there is a possibility they will fail to produce the expected result.

That being said, here are a few things you can try. You may need to combine them to get something useful out of them.

## Processes

Since Android is based on a (somewhat) modified Linux kernel, it generally supports most Unix mechanisms for working with processes.

Apps are launched by a process called `zygote`. A quick run of `ps` on an Android device shows me that all user apps (as well as the higher-level system apps) seem to be children of the `zygote` process. Thus you could get a list of all processes, find the PID for `zygote` and grab all its child processes.

Then you might be able to `waitpid()` on each process and examine its exit status. You may want to experiment around with this a bit and see if the exit codes tell you anything about how the process ended.

Also take a look at `ptrace()`. You might be able to monitor `zygote` directly with an option such as `PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK`, which should basically notify you each time a new app is launched, allowing you to monitor its PID as well.

Downside: You probably need to be root to do any of this. Linux doesn’t let users see other users’ processes (which is an essential security feature), and Android harnesses (or abuses) the user model by running each app with a separate Linux UID.

## Logcat

Looking at various logcat apps (e.g. aLogcat), you might be able to monitor the logcat for events like this:

`12-26 10:01:27.670 I/ActivityManager(  774): Process org.openbmap (pid 21647) has died.`

There are a few events that may occur when an app crashes—ActivityManager will tell you when an app has died, or you might watch for unhandled exceptions.

Note: While this doesn’t seem to require root (aLogcat works fine without), it may not work under all conditions. I have seen devices where aLogcat sees next to no entries, though I didn't investigate why. In those cases, the above approach would not work as it depends on being able to read the logcat.